# How to swap two bytes in a list and print it as int ultimately?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a list with 2 integers stored in buffer []. I want the two bytes swapped. For eg, if the first element is 13 and 05 , I need the output as hex string to be read as 050d (ie, swap the original byes 13 and 05 - to make it read as 05 and 13 and then read it as hex). Later I need to convert it to int (1293), which I think I can do it using the int() operator.

I am not very sure about the bitwise operations I am doing. What I did now is:

```
print(hex(buffer[0]<<8 | buffer[1] )[2:])
```

This prints the output as d05. But what I want is 050d. Which I can later convert it to int using the int() feature. Could someone help me with the bitshift operation please? Thanks!

Explaining more:
This is my sample program:

```
    buffer = []

def func():
    global buffer
    buffer.append(13)
    buffer.append(05)

func()
print(buffer)

print(hex(buffer[0]<<8 | buffer[1] )[2:])
```

This prints b05, whereas my desired output is 050b.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean that "the first element is 13 (0d in hex) and 05 (05 in hex)"--the first element is 13 and the second element is 05, or the first element is 0d05 in hex, or something else? Are the sizes of the integers guaranteed to be the appropriate size (up to 15 or 255, depending on the answer to my previous question)? Can the operations used be character-based or must they be arithmetic and bit-twiddling? A *full* example input and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Added the program to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: You have answered my question about "the first element" but not about element sizes and allowable operations. Also, your code does not match your description of "8 integers stored in buffer"--you have only two integers.

Comment: Hi @RoryDaulton, the first element is 13 and the second element is 05. I want to swap and read (and store) it as hex string ie, 13 and 0d and 05 as 05 (for some purpose later on). My original code is a bit longer and it has 8 elements, but if you could point me to the logic in manipulating first two bytes, I can do it for the other bytes easily :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
print((buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0])
```

This outputs `1293`, that is the final result you wanted assuming you have 8 bit integers (hence the 8). If you also want the hexadecimal representation you can do it like this:

```
print(hex((buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0]))
```

outputs `0x50d`

Comment: format((buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0], '04x') will output 050d